# C# query to combo box

Tags: c#

I am using a combo box to receive data from the ROnumber column upon form load. I would like to see the data from largest number to smallest in the combo box. This is the query I am using. This does work but it does not put it in any certain order.

```
string query = "select * from Inventory where ORDER BY ROnumber DESC ='" + comboRO.Text + "'";
```

Comment: you should use the condition before `ORDER BY`

Comment: Yeah I have switched it every which way I can think of and still no success.

Comment: What is `comboRO` supposed to represent? The `WHERE` and `Order By` syntax you're using is not valid.

Comment: comboRO is what the name of my combo box is on the form.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use parameterized query instead for this; you can use like the following:

```
String sql = "select * from Inventory where someColumnName=@foo ORDER BY ROnumber DESC"; 
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string here")) 
   {
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) 
      {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@foo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = comboRO.Text;
        //execute command here
      }
   }
```

You have to give a valid column name instead for `someColumnName`

Comment: Still not working by descending. Almost like it ignores everything except for the first part of the String. It still carries all of the data over to the combo box but does not sort it.

Comment: @CamlCase It's almost definitely because the combo box is doing its own sorting (or at the very least, not preserving order). Or, you're not adding the data properly. In any case, the SQL query un-lucky provided you *will* sort the results by `ROnumber`.